# Click event is triggered after :active selector

Tags: javascript, css, angular, button, click

in my Angular application, I have a button that has a little animation, it goes down by a few pixels when you click on it :

```
&:active {
   margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
```

It also has a `(click)="myFunction()"` event listener.

The problem is that whenever I click on the top of the button, it doesn't trigger the function because it goes down before and therefore the click isn't situated on the button.

I have made a codesandbox to demonstrate : https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-bx8nd?fontsize=14

Is there any way I can make the 'active' selector trigger after the click event ? Or achive the same effect in some other way ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) for `:active`:

> The :active CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a button) that is being activated by the user. When using a mouse, "activation" typically **starts when the user presses down** the primary mouse button.

And from the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) for a click event:

> click fires after **both** the mousedown and mouseup events have fired, in that order.

So, in a nutshell, your issue is caused because the css transition for `:active` is firing on the `mousedown`, whereas `myFunction()` does not fire until `mouseup`.

Change `(click)="myFunction()"` to `(mousedown)="myFunction()"` and you'll have a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Add styling i.e. document.getElementById("id").style.margin="15px" inside the myFunction().

Answer (score 0):

Use `mouseup` event instead of click.

Working Fiddle - https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-2z45i?fontsize=14

```
test() {
    const btn = document.querySelector("button");
    btn.style.margin = "15px 0 0 0";
    this.clicked++;
    setTimeout(() => {
      btn.style.margin = "";
    }, 100);
  }
```

--HTML--

```
<button class="btn" (mouseup)="test()">Test</button>
```